# Document innerHTML shows old content, on ajax load

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/path/to/dynamic/html",
  type    : "GET"
}).done(function(result){
  $("#content").html(result)
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("Now, the html content is " + document.body.innerHTML )}, 10000)
})
```

`/path/to/dynamic/html` url returns a plain string as,
`i am the dynamic content`

After an expiry of 10 seconds, i expected the console to print,

```
<div id="content">i am the dynamic content</div>
```

But still, the console prints old content as,

```
<div id="content">i am the static content</div>
```

But the page gets rendered with new content.

Why is the `console.log` showing the old DOM content even after setting an expiry of ten seconds?

Comment: can u try this? $.get(url, function (data) {
   $('#content').html(data);
});

Comment: the above code in the given form works... i was passing wrong function argument to `setTimeout` in the original code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have jQuery, use jQuery's methods:

```
$("body").html()
```

When you provide no parameters to the `.html()` method, it returns the HTML.  When you do provide a parameter, it replaces the HTML.

Here is a reference to the [`.html()` method in the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/html/) for further information about the method.

---

**Edit:**

So to apply this to your code, you'd do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/path/to/dynamic/html",
  type    : "GET"
}).done(function(result){
  $("#content").html(result)
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("Now, the html content is " + $("body").html() )}, 10000)
})
```

Comment: @SaravanaKumar, that's very strange.  Are you sure the HTML is changing to begin with?

Comment: Jamen, you are correct... i did a blunder in passing function argument to `setTimeout`. instead of giving the value as third argument, i gave `func_arg(arg1)`. But, in trying to simplify the error, i forgot to capture that point... thank you...